# Design Patterns: Builder within a Factory

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern, builder-pattern

I'm wondering if this is a valid practice of design patterns. I'm currently designing a code where it seems that there is a builder within the factory. I can smell something bad in my current design but I can't pinpoint it. The code looks something like this...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string productName = "productA";
        IProduct product1 = new Factory().GetNewProduct(productName);
    }
}

class Factory
{
    internal IProduct GetNewProduct(string name)
    {
        IProduct product = null;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "productA":
                product = new ProductA();
                break;
            case "productB":
                product = new ProductB();
                break;
            case "productC":
                product = new ProductC();
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid product type!");
        }

        //builder (sort of)            
        product.addPart1();
        product.addPart2();
        ...

        return product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that there is no any flexibility
in building the IProduct object, all objects are built in the same way, so if tomorrow some object need to be created in some other way. You will have to do heavy changes. What I would suggest is having a Factory method inside the Builder class as follows

```
class Builder {

    IProduct product;

    public Builder(String type) {

        product = new Factory().getNewProduct(type);
    }

    public Builder addPart1() {

        product.addPart1();
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addPart2() {

        product.addPart2();
        return this;
    }

    public void build() {

        return product;
    }


    private class Factory {

        IProduct GetNewProduct(string name) {
            IProduct product = null;

            switch (name)
            {
                case "productA":
                    product = new ProductA();
                    break;
                case "productB":
                    product = new ProductB();
                    break;
                case "productC":
                    product = new ProductC();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Invalid product type!");
            }

            return product;
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        String productName = "productA";
        IProduct product1 = new Builder(productName)
                            .addPart1()
                            .addPart2()
                            .build();
    }
}
```

In this approach you can independently add more product types (in your Factory method) and build your object step by step with more parts :)

Comment: +1 nice. it's true that my current products are built the same way and your approach would make it more flexible.
I'll try to refactor my code and will feedback the results on how it looks after. :)

Comment: just implemented your approach to my code. looks great! Thank you very much!

the only question I have is if it's still necessary to create the factory class inside the builder?
What I did was just include the GetNewProduct method in the builder class instead of creating a nested factory.

Comment: Also, let's say ProductA only need to have Part1, so it's reasonable to implement AddPart1() in ProductA class... but say ProductB has a Part2, since they both share Product Interface, they both need to implement AddPart2(). I was forced to implement ProductA AddPart1() without any lines of code.. (i.e. { } only)

Comment: Factory method is good enough as long as things aren't complex and for your second question, it depends on how many things they share in common, if not much then no point of having a same interface.