# C++ Evil Getter Setter against Factory/Builder design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, getter-setter

I'm trying to learn the design pattern norme (like refacturing guru), and i have some problem to understand how i could merge the idea of bad design with public getter/setter and factory/Builder that need "out of constructor" variable setter.

for example with the answer of this article to [article to Design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524096/design-patterns-builder-within-a-factory)

As you can understand, each object will need a lot of informations, and adding part should set the needed informations, but to be able to do it, it need accessor to my variable outside the constructor.

Help me figure out what i'm missing.

--- Edit
To be more precise, Let's say i have 2 class :
CombatObject <---- Spaceships
And i have a factory that will create different type of spaceships (principally because i don't want to create more than 10 class just to change the stats of the objects)

in this case, getter/setter are not a bad design (or are they?)

Comment: A factory is used to generate different kinds of child classes based on a criterium.  The getter/setter is used to change the state of an object's data member.  IMHO, one can't be substituted for the other.

Comment: You could also implement the Clone pattern.  The factory will generate a ship.  The Ship's clone method can create duplicate ships; then you can alter those clones.

Comment: In my opinion getters and setters are usually a bad idea. Prefer to have methods that do things to the object rather than get data from the object, manipulate it, and then set the result. If you have a `public` setter that does nothing but set the member's value, you have effectively made the member `public`. A good setter will do *something* else, like protect the class by testing for and rejecting invalid values.

Comment: @user4581301: Having a simple public getter/setter has one advantage over making the member public. If I install the getter and setter in my class today, and other people start writing code that uses them, I can modify them -- and the member itself -- tomorrow. If I give everyone public access to the member itself today, I'll have a hell of a time taking it back.

Comment: True, and you can also hang a breakpoint on it. I should have worded that comment a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i think the  comments are right, the way i see the solution is the following :

No Setter, the only way to interact with the object will be with function with a purpose.
For exemple, modify HP, add a DoDamage function that will return false if the ship is destoyed and will internally modify the hp (and maybe the damage too, etc..)

Getter can be public, but of course, only "const &"

Clone method is a good idea for future development (prototype pattern)